# in C# is it possible to put PerformanceCounter on a process tree

Tags: c#, performancecounter

I know how to get current process' performance counters. But is it possible to get them from a child process and all its children in total, when children are
a) managed code
b) native binaries ?

Answer (score 1):

Child process `InstanceName`s are the parent's name with an appended #n. With that, this may be helpful. The following gets the sum of processor time for all Chrome's processes:

```
(new PerformanceCounterCategory("Process"))
.GetInstanceNames()
.Where(a => a.StartsWith("chrome"))
.Select(a => new PerformanceCounter("Process", "% Processor Time", a).NextValue())
.Sum()
```